# Set toolbar color and navigationbar back button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want to set the background color of the toolbar in iOS7:
 I am setting the color with this:

```
toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,flexible,barButtonOther,nil];
toolBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdownbar"]];
```

But the background image is not displaying.

[image]

And I want to know what this does:

```
 NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"]];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
} else {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"]];

}
```

Nd how to change back button color of default navigation bar:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Toolbar or NavigationBar they're two completely different things. A navigationBar goes at the top a toolbar would normally go at the bottom.

Comment: @Popeye i knew that..but i want to know that what will that code do?

Comment: I was actually talking about your image. If that is at the top it should be a navigationBar not a toolbar.

Comment: but it is not on top it is in bottom and the code of navigation bar is different i just want to know meaning of that code

Comment: OK, it's just the way you have put your image it looks like status bar >> toolbar >> view. My mistake sorry. See my answer for explanation of that code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS 7 you have to use `toolbar.barTintColor` to set a color, `toolbar.tintColor` will set the color of the barButtons inside the toolbar.

The last piece of code tests if the app is running on iOS 7, if it is `barTintColor` is used, if it's not, `tintColor` will be used.

To change the backButton you can do the same by setting `tintColor` of the navigationBar

Comment: i did this then my done and other button disappeared;

Comment: I you use `tintColor` and `barTintColor` on the toolbar with the same color, your buttons and the toolbar will have the same color.

Comment: no no you are right its worked...by mistake i have removed line which add button to toolbar ... :)

Comment: for back button i have done this...but not worked.
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]` should do it :)

Answer (score 2):

This code is basically determining what the iOS is and selecting the correct method call to set the `tintColor` of the navigationBar. See comments in code below

```
/* This is basically getting the systemVersion of the device so 7.0.1 - as this is returned
   as an NSString the user is separating this string based on the string "." which will
   place each string into the array. so you will have 3 objects in this array of "7", "0", "1"
 */
NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
/* Once we have separated this string into the array we are getting the first object in that array
   so index `0` which will return a string at which point we are converting the string "7" to
   an intValue and comparing it to the int 7. So if that value is 7 or greater return TRUE
 */
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    /* The value was TRUE so lets use the iOS 7 way of setting the tintColor.
       We do this by setting barTintColor for the navigationBar and because
       in iOS 7 the navigationBar can be translucent - by default this is YES
       but because we are setting to a color we want we need to set this to NO
       because we don't want to have it translucent.
     */
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"]];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
} else {
    /* 
     If all fails in the if statements conditional check we must be on something 
     that is below iOS 7 so use the old way of things and just set the tintColor
     */
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"]];
}
```

Just so you know this doesn't work. If you are going to use this change it to:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) => NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"]];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
} else {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"]];
}
```

this is because `if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7)` will return FALSE even if iOS 7.

To set the toolbar you could use the same method but replace:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"]];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

with

```
[toolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdownbar"]]];
[toolbar setTranslucent:NO];
```

and replace

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"]];
```

with

```
 [toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdownbar"]]];
```

Comment: great...and if i am targeting only ios7 for my app then no need to check os version right...directly with bartintcolor ??

Comment: That's right if you're only supporting iOS 7+ and your deployment target is iOS 7 then there is no need for the `if statement` because the else part will never in a million years be reached. So YES you could just set `barTintColor:`

Answer (score 1):

```
//How to set color of  *all* navigationbars and toolbars in an app in Swift 2.0

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

      func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptionslaunchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
         UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.greenColor(); // All back button in the app are now green.
         UIToolbar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor(); // All toolBar icons in the app are now orange.

        //........
        let returnCode: Bool = getAppSpecificReturnCode();



       return returnCode
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code...

```
[toolBar setBackgroundImage:toolBarIMG forToolbarPosition:0 barMetrics:0];
```